# Wifi connection drops randomly on windows10 but working normaly on ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, router

I dual boot windows 10 and ubuntu 22.04 ,my wifi connection working normaly on ubuntu, but when i switch to use windows 10, my wifi connection drop randomly and very frequently, when connection drops, i have to disable my wifi device and enable it again to reconnect to my wifi router. Can someone explain why? this is very annoying, and something unsual is that on ubuntu my wifi device is Qualcomm Atheros 9462 but on windows it is atheros 946x, i dont know why 2 os see diferent things

Comment: Try updating the Windows driver for the wireless card. Make sure it is compatible with Windows

Comment: I did that, but it didnt help

Comment: Maybe try a different wireless card.  Get a USB Wireless Adapter and try that.